# windows command line script variable going wrong somewhere?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, variables

Battling with a windows command line script I just can't get to work.

Basically I am trying to launch a program called vnctv.exe with the parameters of HOST ipaddress PORT 5900 PASSWORD x, however I only want to run the program with IP addresses of computers currently online.

I've tried a few different things but I cant get anything to work properly.

It seems when I run cmd and type in the commands individually they all work correctly but when I run it in a .bat file it fails.

I have tried enabledelayedexpansion so I wouldn't need to call but I couldn't get that to work.

The for loop first loops through 30-255 addresses. The next loop pings the IP and finds the loss rate. If it's 0 then I need to add that address to a run parameter for vnctv.exe. I've tried echoing to file then removing the \n characters but can't get that to work either. So the script should add the parameter to a variable but it fails.

here it is

```
set _megga=vnctv.exe

FOR /L %%A IN (253,1,255) DO (

    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%%" %%B 
     IN ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.%%A -w 500 -n 1 ^|find "loss"')
     DO ( if %%B EQU 0 call :exec ))
 )

:exec

set %%_megga=%_megga% HOST 91.40.20.%%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x

goto :EOF

echo %%_megga > run.bat
run.bat
```

and heres the output

```
Z:\>set _megga=vnctv.exe

Z:\>FOR /L %A IN (253 1 255) DO (FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%" %B IN ('PING -w 500
 -n 1 91.40.20.%A -w 500 -n 1 |find "loss"') DO (if %B EQU 0 call :exec  ) )

Z:\>(FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%" %B IN ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.253 -w 500 -n
 1 |find "loss"') DO (if %B EQU 0 call :exec  ) )

Z:\>(if 0 EQU 0 call :exec  )

Z:\>set %_megga=vnctv.exe HOST 91.40.20.%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x

Z:\>goto :EOF

Z:\>(FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%" %B IN ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.254 -w 500 -n
 1 |find "loss"') DO (if %B EQU 0 call :exec  ) )

Z:\>(if 0 EQU 0 call :exec  )

Z:\>set %_megga=vnctv.exe HOST 91.40.20.%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x

Z:\>goto :EOF

Z:\>(FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%" %B IN ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.255 -w 500 -n
 1 |find "loss"') DO (if %B EQU 0 call :exec  ) )

Z:\>(if 100 EQU 0 call :exec  )

Z:\>set

%_megga=vnctv.exe HOST 91.40.20.%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x

_megga=vnctv.exe

Z:\>set %_megga=vnctv.exe HOST 91.40.20.%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x

Z:\>goto :EOF
```

When I set it should read 91.40.20.254 for instance instead of %A and also it's making 2 different variables

Thanks for any Help

Adam

tried this but still getting %1 or 1 instead of the actual value

```
 set _megga=vnctv.exe
 FOR /L %%A IN (253,1,255) DO (
 FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%%" %%B IN 
 ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.%%A -w 500 -n 1 ^|find "loss"') 
 DO ( if %%B EQU 0 call :exec %%A))

 :exec
 set %%_megga=%%_megga HOST 91.40.20.%%1 PORT 5900 PASSWORD x
 goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial complaint that your cmd processor is throwing out is that you dont seem to end the `tokens=2 delims=(%` options string.  This is because you are using the special `%` in your delim set.  Try putting a double `%` there:

```
"tokens=2 delims=(%%"
```

Here is a different strategy to approach your problem:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set _megga=vnctv.exe
echo echo running %_megga% batch > run.bat
FOR /L %%A IN (253,1,255) DO (

    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=(%%" %%B IN ('PING -w 500 -n 1 91.40.20.%%A -w 500 -n 1 ^|find "loss"') DO ( 
          if %%B EQU 0 set _megga=!_megga! HOST 91.40.20.%%A PORT 5900 PASSWORD x ))
 )
echo %_megga% >> run.bat
run.bat
```

I have taken the gist of your loops, but instead of jumping out to a label, I concatenate the command in the loop and later echo it to the `run.bat` which can then be run at the end.  You will note that I employ the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!` to replace `%` in the loop.

Comment: Thankyou this does work however it launches the application several times where as I need to launch the application only once and include all parameters in that one call.

Comment: Adam, note my most recent changes in response to your comment.

Comment: AHA brilliant thanks that's where I had been going wrong thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

try escaping %:

"tokens=2 delims=(%%"

Edit: to reflect comment
Also note that that the inner for loop's variables can clash with the the outers. When %G is set, the other tokens after G (%h & %i) may be overwritten. I suggest you change %i in the outer loop to be %a.